# What is the relationship between onChange and value when using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react, I am not clear about the relationship between `onChange` and `value` in `input` tag. If `onChange` has update any variable that is declared above using `useState` with empty `value`, it causes error. Why does it happen?
I think example code makes my question clear so here is an example.

```
from React, { useState } import 'react'

function example() {
    const [example,setExample] = useState('');

    return (
    <input type="text" onChange={e=> setExample(e.target.value} value={} />
    )
}
```

In `input` tag, there is no specific variable as `value` attribute. If I put `example` as value, it works properly. Why does it act like it? What I thought was since the `example` has declared at above, no matter what `value` is, it should work properly.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why `value={}`? remove it and it will work properly

Comment: Remove `value={}` attribute in input if you don't need then it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In React everything is object. The HTML structure you see in the return is also an object and input object needs a key value for updating the actual value.
To understand this you can consider your input like this

```
input {
value : <VALUE>
onChange : <YOUR_FUNTION_THAT_UPDATES_VALUE>
}
```

To map the values in the input you have to assign the value as {example} in the input object and any change in the value will re-render your input object.

```
from React, { useState } import 'react'

function example() {
    const [example,setExample] = useState('');

    return (
    <input type="text" onChange={e=> setExample(e.target.value} value={example} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**React, as word suggest reacts to any event which occurs in your web page**, now when a change is occurred in the text of the input, we need to update our state to hold the value that use just typed in for future uses.

Also we need value in our input field to be able to post it, that why we use value in value property like

`value={value}`

and in order to update the value variable as user types in, we hook up an event to update value (State) whenever anything changes.